# Envio de variáveis função ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma função Ajax, que ao tirar o foco do campo desconto, ele verifica no banco de dados e me traz um array de resultados via json, e com este resultado eu verifico se o desconto é maior que o permitido e preencho o campo desconto automaticamente. A função funciona certinho quando envio apenas a variavel `idproduto`, quando envio uma outra variável junto ele não funciona.
Eu coloquei o `console.log(modalidade)`antes do ´$.ajax({` e a modalidade aparece.

```
                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'buscadescontoproduto.php',
                        type: 'GET', // As variaveis são enviadas como $_GET;
                        dataType: 'JSON', // E o retorno dever ser feito em JSON;
                        data: {idproduto:idproduto, modalidade:modalidade}, // Variaveis;

                        beforeSend: function () {
                             //Pode ser colocado um loading aqui, exemplo;
                            //$('#desconto' + x).val('Carregando...');
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                           
                          },
                       });
```

O codigo php onde recebo as variaveis:

```
<?php
    require('../Paginas/verificasession.php');
    if (isset($_GET['idproduto'])) {
     $idproduto = $_GET['idproduto'];
     $modalidade = $_GET['modalidade'];
    include '../Config/config.php';
    $return_arr = array();
    if ($con) {        
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT tabeladepreco.desconto 
                                        FROM produtos,tabeladepreco 
                                        where produtos.idproduto = $idproduto 
                                        AND tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto 
                                        AND tabeladepreco.modalidade = $modalidade 
                                        AND produtos.ativo = 1 ");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {

            $row_array['desconto'] = utf8_encode($row['desconto']);
            array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
        exit();
       }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Sr não passar a modalidade, deveria dar erro no seu php. Passando, depende do tipo da variável. Se não for numérica, também vai dar erro, pela maneira como você interpola o valor da variável na query.

Comment: Amigo, Entender o erro vai ser vital pra definir o problema
o erro pode ser sua interpretação do que deveria acontecer, exemplo de enviar tanto com um quanto com dois parâmetros o resultado é o mesmo.
Também se a resposta do php vem vazia ou simplesmente retorna uma exceção. se puder esclarecer esses pontos poderei ajudar

Comment: @EduardoWorrel quando envio apenas com uma variável funciona, o resultado vem, a resposta do Json no php vem com o valor, mas quando envio os dois, não da erro , ela vem vazia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após ler os comentários do @bfavaretto, verifiquei uma forma de passar as duas variáveis numéricas e assim funcionou.